# How to get the Attributes collection in a Tag using Watin?

Tags: attributes, tags, element, watin

Can I get all the attributes exist in an Element?

I need this to iterate to all attributes in the element and get the values!

I have searched in the Element class but I can't see any property or method specific to return a collection of attribute string names so I can iterate and GetAttributeValue....

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method to do this a while back because (as far as I know), there's isn't anything built into WatiN.  I've not had any problems with this code since, but I still consider it a horrible hack!  Maybe one of the smarter posters on here can help improve it!  HTH!

Phil

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (IE browser = new IE("www.google.co.uk"))
    {
        Div div = browser.Div("hplogo");
        Dictionary<string, string> attrs = GetAllAttributeValues(div);
    }
}

private Dictionary<string, string> GetAllAttributeValues(Element element)
{
    if (element == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Supplied element is null");
    if (!element.Exists)
        throw new ArgumentException("Supplied element does not exist");

    string html = element.OuterHtml; // element html (incl children)
    int idx = html.IndexOf(">");
    Debug.Assert(idx != -1);
    html = html.Substring(0, idx + 1).Trim(); // element html without children

    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    while ((idx = html.IndexOf('=')) != -1)
    {
        int spaceIdx = idx - 1;
        while (spaceIdx >= 0 && html[spaceIdx] != ' ')
            spaceIdx--;
        Debug.Assert(spaceIdx != -1);

        string attrName = html.Substring(spaceIdx + 1, idx - spaceIdx - 1);
        string attrValue = element.GetAttributeValue(attrName);
        result.Add(attrName, attrValue);

        html = html.Remove(0, idx + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just spotted a potential issue with this code.  If one of the attribute values contains '=', it'll try and parse it as another attribute :S  Maybe you could parse the string as xml to get they key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for the same. It provides `HtmlNode.Attributes` as `HtmlAttributeCollection` which can be looped to get attribute names and values.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?